# What's the safest method to access a php file thats outside the root directory?

Tags: php, security, include

I've tried to search this elsewhere on stackoverflow and elsewhere on the net.

Can't seem to get a solid lock on an answer that suggests it's the safest way.

I know that the securest method is, where possible, to not include any php files in the root directory where it can be helped.

So, what I am trying to find out is, if I want to include a php file stored OUTSIDE the root directory, say, in another directory, what is the safest way for me to do that?

Comment: By `root` do you mean your publicly accessable folder aka `public_html`?

Comment: Yes, so the folder that someone could possibly get into and meddle with to do damage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to directly answer your question, but maybe it will get you to look at your app structure differently. I think it's a misconception that it's *not safe* to include files from outside of your webroot.

On the contrary, many people have a structure where most if not **all** of their application logic is outside of the `public_html` or similar directory. Especially with catch-all router type systems.

You can have a structure like:

```
var
    www
        public
            something.js
            happy.jpg
            index.php
        application
            bootstrap.php
            AwesomeClass.php
            Router.php
```

Now with your `index.php` you can work out the **real** root of your application.

Something like:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
define('PHP_ROOT', APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application');
```

You now have constants that point to the real filesystem path of your public html directory and where your php files are, and can now safely include files like:

`include(PHP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php');`

This is perfectly safe, and many people have apps structured like this. It also prevents people being able  to browse to any php files you have laying around, in the event that you don't have any `.htaccess` or similar voodoo in place.

Comment: Interesting, experimenting with the first two defines there, question though.... how does DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR work? what does it do?

Comment: @Kalcoder: Its an OS specific constant. On Windows it's '\' and on *nix/BSD it's '/'. So your file paths always have the right one.

Comment: Ah I see, so basically it will ensure it either needs to be for example home/somefolderoutsideofpublic/fileimgoingtouse.php or home\somefolderoutsideofpublic\fileimgoingtouse.php , ok cool that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: so if I wanted to go a few directories up I am assuming where for example 'application' is I could go '../../../application' and I am also assuming because it's made as a constant there's no risk in doing that?

Comment: @Kalcoder: My personal preference would be to avoid relative paths altogether, and always start from from the root, working forwards. But you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I believe that you want to prevent directory travesal (people trying to get your script to include /etc/passwd etc).

Use [realpath](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) on the requested path. This should expand out all the `../`, `..` etc.

Once this is done, you check the result returned by `realpath()` against a whitelist or restrict it to your own directory and check if the `file_exist()` : `file_exist('myfolder' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . $resultFromRealPath())`.